# React/JSX: Can I use a state variable in another state variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have something like this, where I would like to create array in the state from a variable initialized directly above it. I get the error `cards is not defined`. Is there a way around this? I need to set this array specifically in the state.

```
class Example extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cards: [
        {
          name: "Name 1",
          description: "dfdsfaf",
        },
        {
          name: "Name 2",
          description: "dsfsfasf",
        },
        {
          name: "Name 3",
          description: "daslkdjadlajsd",
        },
     ],
      names: cards.map(item => item.name)
    };
   }
...
}
```

Comment: Simply create a local variable with the array, say `const cards = [{/**/}, {/**/}];`, then just used that for both properties. `this.state = { cards, names: cards.map(i => i.name ) };`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in javascript as follows:

```
const cards = [...]
const names = = cards.map(...)
this.state = { cards: cards, names: names }
```

You should probably not do this though and set state to only the cards and move the call to calculate the names to your render method